# Need .NET solution to detect if "East Asian languages" are installed in Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, windows-xp

Environment - C#, .NET 4.0, WPF, VS2010

I have a simple Windows application that supports several cultures/languages. When users select Japanese, Korean, Chinese (Simplified), or Chinese (Traditional), Windows XP will display funny looking "square" or "block" characters in the place of the glyphs. This problem does not occur on Windows Vista, 7 or 8.

As a solution I was advised to go to "Control Panel | Regional and Language Options", select the "Languages" tab, and then check the box to "Install files for East Asian languages".

And that did fix the problem...for my machine. Now I understand that users in Japan who select "Japanese" will most likely already have the necessary resources installed, and they will most likely not experience this problem.

But...I require the ability to detect whether or not the East Asian languages have been installed on any Windows XP machine that is running my app. In such case I will be able to display a message box notifying them to install the languages...or I might decide to hide the Japanese, Korean, Chinese (Simplified) and Chinese (Traditional) culture/language choices.

So...how can I detect if Windows XP has the necessary East Asian language files installed? I prefer a .NET solution, but I am willing to make API calls if necessary.

JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking `InputLanguage`, you should check `CultureInfo` using `GetCultures` function call,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx

As documented, if `InstalledWin32Cultures` is used as parameter, this function should return what you want,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.culturetypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate like this:

```
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage p in System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
            Console.WriteLine(p.Culture.EnglishName);
```

it will display what you are looking for.

Comment: That will tell you if the *INPUT* is supported, the display might be supported even if the input is not.  This Windows XP instance has the fonts installed but no corresponding input methods--I want to be able to display emails in Chinese, my wife is going to answer by phone anyway so there's no need for the input editor.

Comment: No. Don't use Windows.Forms as it is completely removed in .NET 4.5

Comment: @ColeJohnson, who said that? All WinForms stuffs are still available in .NET 4.5. It will be silly if Microsoft makes that kind of decision.

Comment: @LexLi no it isnt. install win 8, vs11, and .net4.5 and you cant referance System.Windows.Forms anymore

Comment: As I am indeed using Windows 8 + VS11, I confirm that I can use System.Windows.Forms.dll freely. What is the project type you use? Any projects (WinForms) you created in older VS can be opened in it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but my inclination would be simply to try it--draw something in an East Asian language and examine the result.  Did you get a box?

Edit: Apparently some people didn't realize I meant to draw the text and then have the code examine the result.  I didn't mean a human eyeball test!

Comment: He wants to programmatically determine if they are installed.